# How does EOF act in getchar() and scanf() on Windows system?

Tags: c, stdin, eof

I have two pieces of codes to test how the two console I/O functions, getchar() & scanf(), handle the EOF. But I still do not have a clear comprehension about the actual operations behind the outputs and their behaviors. Can someone explains that for me? Thanks a lot! (I am using Windows OS)

```
// 1st piece of Code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
   char ch;

   while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF)
   {
      putchar(toupper(ch));
   }

   return 0;
}
```

If I type

```
abc
```

or

```
abc(ctrl+z)
```

> > The program will have the same outputs:
> >
> > ABC

---

```
// 2nd piece of Code
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    while(scanf("%d",&x) != EOF)
    {
        /*Ctrl + z + Enter*/
        printf("x=%d\n",x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I type

```
123
```

> > The program will output:
> >
> > x=123

Otherwise, if I type

```
123(ctrl+z)
```

> > The program will have an infinite output:
> >
> > x=123
> >
> > x=123
> >
> > x=123
> >
> > x=123
> >
> > ...

Comment: The [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function returns an ***`int`***. This is actually very important for that `EOF` comparison.

Comment: This `printf("x=%\n",x);` -> `printf("x=%d\n",x);`

Comment: @Achal Oh! my mistake! I have corrected it.

Comment: With `scanf` you normally test if the return value indicates the number of conversions equals what you expect, here you should compare with `1`. If it is not 1, then no value was read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar()` returns the value of the character converted to `unsigned char` or `EOF` in case of error.

The error can be "end of file" or something else; usually (for `getchar()`) the programmer does not care about the error, just that an error happened.

---

`scanf()` returns the number of values matched and assigned (basically the number of `%` in the format string) or `EOF` in case of error. **Note that the number can be less than the number of `%` in case, for example, of badly formatted input**

Just like for `getchar()` the error can be "end of file" or something else. Particularly, reading less than the number of `%` **is not an error**.

So you may prefer to test for the correct number of assignments rather than testing for error in `scanf()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x;
    while (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) {
        /*Ctrl + z + Enter*/
        printf("x=%d\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on Windows the `EOF` is put into the input buffer like a normal character (with the encoded value `26`).

When reading character by character (with e.g. `getchar`) this is handled by the Windows run-time library. But it doesn't work like that with `scanf` because when `scanf` parses the input it's like another character. And as a non-digit it's an invalid character for te `"%d"` format, leading to your `scanf` Call to return `0` instead of `EOF` (since it's not parsed by the format).

One way to solve it is to press the <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> sequence on its own new line.

Another (and more reliable) way to solve it is to check that [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the number of formats you have in the string. In your case you should compare against `1` (as you have one format specifier).